# Convergence of the recursive sequence $q_n = 1 - (1-pq_{n-1})^k$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

I have to proove that the sequence $$
q_n = 1 - (1-pq_{n-1})^k, q_0 = 1
$$
converges to a point in $[0,1]$ for $p, q_n \in [0,1]$ for all $n$ and $k \geq 1$.

The sequence $q_n$ is a probability measure so is obviously bounded below by $0$. But I have some difficulties prooving that the sequence is decreasing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that $q_{n+1}=u(q_n)$ where the function $u:x\mapsto1-(1-qx)^k$ is nondecreasing hence $q_{n+1}-q_n=u(q_n)-u(q_{n-1})$ has the sign of $q_n-q_{n-1}$. Since $q_1<q_0$, you are done.